# An exception while creating new user signup. Record does not exist or has been deleted. None

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have installed auth_signup module to ensure signup functionality, but when I am trying to signup a new user either public user or template user, I am getting an exception "**Record does not exist or has been deleted. None**"

By investing on this I found that in
*auth_signup/res_users.py*, exception is where the following line of code are:

```
try:
    with cr.savepoint():
        return self.copy(cr, uid, template_user_id, values, context=context)
```

I don't why cr.savepoint is returning None

Comment: `print vars(cr)` and also share with us the implementation of the method `savepoint()`

Comment: George cr is a database instance object. You can find the implementation of savepoint() here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/sql_db.py#L402